# Authorization header required Fitbit Swift oauth

Tags: swift, oauth, fitbit

So the error I am getting is:HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized, Response: {"errors":[{"errorType":"invalid_request","message":"Authorization header required.

The code I have to authorize Fitbit is :

```
func authorizeFitbit(completion: (result: Bool) -> Void ){
        oauthswift.accessTokenBasicAuthentification = true
        let state: String = generateStateWithLength(20) as String
        oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "xxxxxxxxx")!, scope: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", state: state, success: {
            credential, response, parameters in
            self.getUserProfile(){
                (result: Bool) in
                completion(result:  result)
            }

            }, failure: { error in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(result:  false)
        })
        }
```

I am able to grab profile information but when I am trying to grab more information from fitbit by clicking on an IBAction button, I am required to use this authorize function again to grab the number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

The question may need more details to be properly answered.

- What OAuth grant type are you using?
- What is the `oauthswift` class you are using? Your own or third party?
- You are stating that you are able to grab profile information. Should that be read as you been able to get the whole way through for whatever grant type you are using but get problems when you want to execute a new request to the resource server?

Some other OAuth implementations require you to set the Authorization HTTP-header with the actual token type and the actual access_token when you send your requests to the resource server. The following is an example for Microsoft Azure AD using Authorization Code flow:

```
GET /v1.0/me/messages
Host: https://graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSU...
```

Another possibility, if I compare to the "Authorization Code" grant type, the "invalid_request" error implies that you have not got pass the first stage in the request flow, that error you get before requesting the access token.

EDIT: Didn't see how old this question was. Well, I let the reply be here anyway, maybe it helps someone one day...